# Add Get parameter to every url in website (like fbclid/gclid)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Hello i would like to add get parameter to my links in my websites without changing them in files just automatically add ?custom=something to all urls without refreshing
Similar to fbclid or gclid

Comment: appending the same GET param to all pages without refreshing or editing files just like facebook with fbclid or google with gclid (i don't want to redirect just to add that get parameter so i can save some data)

Comment: Wait, you want to add the parameter inside the links of your page, so to all your hrefs or have it be re-directed to a different page no matter of whether the link is added?

Comment: Depends on the rules, all links, certain links, ones that already have `?somethingelse=something` or not?

Comment: no the GET parameter won't affect the redirecting just adding php data not redirecting to a whole another page

Comment: Are you able to change `php.ini` do you have a header and footer page that is included on all other pages?  Not enough info.

Comment: If you're trying to pass data to all pages on your website through a query string, that is not the best practice. What exactly are you using this query string parameter for?

Comment: @AbraCadaver  all links (they won't have ?somethingelse)

Comment: Well, my other questions and how do you determine what `?custom=something` will be or is it always the same?  You might just use a session.  There are probably 255 words or more of info missing from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for what are you asking

```
var parameter = '?example=test'
for (var x = 0; x < document.links.length; x++) {
    links = document.links[x];
    links.src = links.src + parameter;
}
for (x = 0; x < document.getElementsByTagName("a").length; x++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[x].href = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[x].href + parameter;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting it correctly, you can add the following to your php files:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['custom'])){
    $newUrl =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?custom=something';
    header("Location: ".$newUrl);
    exit();
}
```

If you do that, remember `header` commands must be placed before you output anything to the client

Or if you do not care about catching anything on the server, you can do a location overwrite with javascript, like so:

```
history.pushState({},"URL Rewrite Example","https://example.com/example?custom=something")
```